# Redirect Users to the welcome page if not registered in SharePoint Application

Tags: 2007

Need some pointer on the best way to implement this requirement in SharePoint

" The content on the SharePoint site is only accessible to the registered users, so when the users  visits the site for the first time, we have to be redirect users to the registration screen. Once registers the regular home page should appear.

I think we have write a custom HTTP Module and Plugin, I am from asp.net background so, I would like to know what is the best way to implement this requirement in the SharePoint 2007.

Thanks

Comment: What is the authentication mechanism?  Windows Integrated (NTLM/Kerberos) or FBA?

Comment: Windows Integrated (NTLM), does it make any difference if its kerberos ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done something similar, where we wanted certain meta data to be set by the user before they could use the intranet.

We did this by checking a user property when the user logged on. If the property was not set, we redirected to an application page where the user must select a value for the property before they could proceed. A similar approach could be used for registration.

Technically we did this as a delegate web control on the front page that used SPUtility.Redirect to redirect to the application page if the property was not set.

Comment: @Anders : Thanks for your answer, but I just have one comment on this; the code will be executed after the page is loaded, I think it would be better if used HTTPModule, any strong reason on the reason for using delegate control instead of a HTTPModule??

Comment: I guess an HttpModule would impact more performance wise for all users. If you use a delegate control you only penalize the users who arent registered yet, since you do a client redirect. Also a delegate control gives you more flexibility if you only want it to be called on some pages not other. Finally a delegate control can be substituted with another control quite easily if you want to change the behaviour.